# Is it true that every eigenvalue has at least one eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

As mentioned above: Is it true that every eigenvalue has at least one eigenvector?

Or is it possible that while trying to find the basis of a specific eigenspace, i will get only the zero vector (means there are no eigenvectors corresponding to this eigenvalue)?

Thank you

Comment: By definition, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$ if (and only if) there is a $v\neq 0$ with $f(v) = \lambda v$.

Comment: You could in theory define an eigenvalue to be a root of the characteristic polynomial of $f$. Michael's answer provides half of the proof that these two definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 12):

I assume you are talking of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an $n\times n$ square matrix $A$.

Define an eigenvalue to be a root of the polynomial $|\lambda I-A|=0$.  Then $\lambda I-A$ has determinant $0$.  So when you row-reduce it, there will be a row of zeros.  There will be at most $n-1$ pivots, so one column lacks a pivot - it is a free variable.  So there are non-zero solutions to $(\lambda I-A)v=0$, or $Av=\lambda v$.

Comment: Are you saying, [A - I] can never have rank = n?

Comment: Yes.  If it has rank $n$ then its columns span an $n$-dimensional space, which is all of $\mathbb R^n$. By the rank theorem, its nullspace is zero-dimensional, and only contains the zero vector.  So there is no nonzero vector $v$ with (A-\lambda I)v=0$, or $Av=\lambda v$, and do no eigenvector.